# Module Error In Python When Running Commands To A Sql Database

Tags: python

Visual Studio is throwing a module error every time I run the code complete the questions and it comes to executing.
This is the error that is printed

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "c:/Users/War/Downloads/CPUS
>   (2) (2).py", line 105, in 
>       create_entry()   File "c:/Users/War/Downloads/CPUS (2) (2).py", line 95, in create_entry
>       c.execute(sql_query,tuple_insert) sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: Cpus

I have looked at other programs I have written and I don't seem to see a problem with the statement and its placement

```
import sqlite3
with sqlite3.connect("Cpus.db") as connection:
        print(connection)
        c = connection.cursor()

def create_entry():
    with sqlite3.connect("Cpus.db") as connection:
        c = connection.cursor()
        append_table_manu = input("What Is The Manufacture Name Of The Cpu You Are Adding? ")
        append_table_cpu = input("What Is The Name Of Your Cpu You Are Adding? ")
        while True:    
                try:
                        append_table_cost = int(input("How Much Does The Cpu You Are Adding Cost? (E.g $99)"))
                except:
                        print("Please Type A Number")         
                        continue
                if append_table_cost > 100000:
                        print("Please Type The Actual Cost Of Your Cpu")
                elif append_table_cost < 0:
                        print("Please Type The Actual Cost Of Your Cpu")
                else:
                    break
        while True:    
                try:
                        append_table_speed = int(input("What Is The Speed Of The Cpu That You Are Adding?, (E.g 2.4) "))
                except:
                        print("Please Type A Number")         
                        continue
                if append_table_speed > 7:
                        print("Please Type The Actual Speed Of Your Cpu")
                elif append_table_speed < 0:
                        print("Please Type The Actual Speed Of Your Cpu")
                else:
                        break
        while True:    
                try:
                        append_table_cores = int(input("How Many Cores Does The Cpu You Are Adding Have? "))
                except:
                        print("Please Type A Number")         
                        continue
                if append_table_cores > 16:
                        print("Please Type The Actual Core Amount Of Your Cpu")
                elif append_table_cores < 0:
                        print("Please Type The Actual Core Amount Of Your Cpu")
                else:
                        break
        while True:    
                try:
                        append_table_threads = int(input("How Many Threads Does The Cpu That You Are Adding Have?, (E.g 99) "))
                except:
                        print("Please Type A Number")         
                        continue
                if append_table_threads > 10000:
                        print("Please Type The Actual Thread Amount Of Your Cpu")
                elif append_table_threads < 0:
                        print("Please Type The Actual Thread Amount Of Your Cpu")
                else:
                        break
        tuple_insert = (append_table_manu, append_table_cpu, append_table_cost, append_table_speed, append_table_cores, append_table_threads)
        sql_query = ("INSERT INTO Cpus (Manufacture,Name_,Cost,Speed_GHz,Cores,Threads) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)")
        c.execute(sql_query,tuple_insert)
        results = c.fetchall()
        print(tuple_insert)
        for i in results:
                print("".format(i[0],i[1]))


while True: #Puts Everything In A Loop     
        option_1 = int(input("What Would You Like To Do To The Cpu Database, 1) Make An Entry, 2) Read The Data Or 3) Delete Data. Type 1, 2, ,3 "))
        if option_1 == 1:
                create_entry()   
        break
```

I haven't completely tested the program because of this error so I don't expect it to completely work as of yet. If any other errors are seen please note them as well...

Comment: how are you creating the database, the tables etc.. ? Did you check if the table `Cpus` **is** already here ?

Comment: The table already exists

Comment: This whole database already exists and it says its connecting but It's not, and yes I already have a table called Cpus, the program works at school but not on my personal computer

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to `CREATE TABLE` before trying to insert any data into it. Also remember that you need to be in the right schema. You normally access the table like this: `schema.table`.

Comment: Maybe you're not hitting the database that you're thinking about. Have you tried running a `SELECT` on this table while initializing the session in the exact same way that you do when you're trying to insert data into it? My guess is that you're creating a new DB file while initializing the session because you're not providing a full path to the DB file.